# Which article to be used in the following sentence?

Tags: articles

Can anyone help me with the use of article in the below sentence.

I am ______ monarch of all I survey.

If possible even reason out why it is used.

Comment: But for your example, [*the article is almost never included.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am+the+monarch+of+all%2Cam+monarch+of+all&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20the%20monarch%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20monarch%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0) We often omit the article before "official position" nouns, as with *I'm president of our local chess club, He's chief executive of the company*.

Comment: Either or none. It's impossible to say from the syntax alone. Only you can determine exactly what you want to convey—which will then determine what article (if any) to use.